# I need to find the count values using a specific row that matches the columns for the other dataframe the values which are true

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For example I have two dataframes

df = [{'id':1, 'A': 'False', 'B' : 'False' , 'C':'NA'},{'id':2, 'A': 'True', 'B' : 'False' , 'C':'NA'}]

df2 = [{'A':'True', 'B': 'False' , 'C':'NA', 'D': 'True'}]

idea should be to count the values based on the row of df which matches, df2 columns

df:

| id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | False | False | NA |
| 2 | True | False | NA |

df2:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | False | NA | True |

Output:

| id | A | B | C | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | False | False | NA | 0 |
| 2 | True | False | NA | 1 |

I tried something like

for i in range(columns):
x = action_value_counts_df.columns[i]
if compare_column.equals(action_value_counts_df[x]):
print(x, 'Matched')
else:
print(x,'Not Matched')

This code did not help

Comment: are you comparing only `A` and `B` columns? cause column `C` is "always" matched

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thanks for the reply I am comparing only the columns which is matched by the row and counts the value the false and NA should be ignored

Answer (score 0):

1. Merge `df`, `df2` using overlapping columns.
2. Count overlapping columns.
3. Merge count result DataFrame into `df`.
4. Replace NA with 0 in the 'Count' column.

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'id':1, 'A': 'False', 'B' : 'False' , 'C':'NA'},
    {'id':2, 'A': 'True', 'B' : 'False' , 'C':'NA'}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    {'A':'True', 'B': 'False' , 'C':'NA', 'D': 'True'}])

# 1
match_df = pd.merge(left=df, right=df2, on=['A', 'B', 'C'], how='inner')
match_df = match_df.assign(Count=1)
"""
   id     A      B   C     D  Count
0   2  True  False  NA  True      1
"""

# 2
match_count_df = match_df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'], as_index=False).count()
match_count_df = match_count_df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'Count']]
"""
      A      B   C  Count
0  True  False  NA      1
"""

# 3
result_df = pd.merge(left=df, right=match_count_df, how='left')
"""
   id      A      B   C  Count
0   1  False  False  NA    NaN
1   2   True  False  NA    1.0
"""

# 4
result_df.loc[:, 'Count'] = result_df['Count'].fillna(0)
"""
   id      A      B   C  Count
0   1  False  False  NA    0.0
1   2   True  False  NA    1.0
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two dataframes rowwise with arranged columns (from `df` to `df2`) and ignored `NaN` values (as they are not comparable):

```
df.assign(Count=df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: (x.dropna() == df2[x.index].squeeze().dropna()).all() * 1, axis=1).values)
```

---

```
  id      A      B   C  Count
0  1  False  False NaN      0
1  2   True  False NaN      1
```